# WooCommerce product taxonomies and menu export

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, import, export

I need to move my data to the new site. I want to export my category menu and product categories and child categories and import them into new WordPress website. I have tried all available plugins I can find but found no solution. I have successfully exported menu and imported it into new website and now I need to move my product categories as I have more than 2000 categories including three levels of subcategories.

Comment: Export everything, then import to the new site and remove any content under any taxonomy.